# Python : Print function is not giving excepted output

Tags: python, dataframe

I have written below function in Python:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [32, 33, 33,34,44]})

def PROC_FREQ(dataset,arg1):
        x= dataset.groupby(arg1)[arg1[0]].agg(({'Frequency':'count'}))
        nombre=x.columns.tolist()[0]
        x.rename(columns={nombre:'Freq'},inplace=True)
        x['Pct']=round((x['Freq']/x.Freq.sum())*100,2)
        x['Freq Acum'],x['Cumm Percent']=x.Freq.cumsum(),x.Pct.cumsum()
        x.sort_values(arg1,ascending=[1],inplace=True)
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns',500)
        x=x.reset_index()
        string_repr = x.to_string(index=False,justify='center').splitlines()
        string_repr.insert(1, "-" * len(string_repr[0]))
        out = '\n'.join(string_repr)
        df_split = out.split('\n')
        columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
        for i in range(len(df_split)):
            print(df_split[i].center(columns))
```

and below is the code to call the function:

```
PROC_FREQ(df,['age'])
```

and below is the output of the function:

```
           age  Freq   Pct   Freq Acum  Cumm Percent                    
           -----------------------------------------                    
           32     1   16.67      1          16.67                       
           33     2   33.33      3          50.00                       
           34     1   16.67      4          66.67                       
             44     2   33.33      6         100.00
```

Last line the output is not aligned correctly.

Comment: maybe the justification to center (`to_string(index=False,justify='center')`) is the problem because your last row has one more characters than previous three.

Comment: I tried Jutify='left'. Rest all lines in the output shifted to left except last line. It seems some other issue.

Comment: Can you print the `repr` of each line? If, say, there are tabs in it, or if there are Windows `\r\n` newlines and you're leaving a `\r` at the end of every line but the last, that could easily confuse things.

Comment: Also, if you could turn this into a [mcve] that we can actually run without needing to have your `df` (or just add a `df = pd.DataFrame(…)` to give us a working example, but it would be better to just remove all the irrelevant stuff and create the final `x` that you're building), it would be a lot easier to debug, instead of having to ask you to do the debugging tests.

Comment: I have edited above code to include creation of dataframe. Now it is a working example. Also I have added some code to make it more presentable and at center of screen.